# Resize embeded FLIPBOOK in a .fla file

Tags: actionscript-3, resize, flash, embed, external

I’m having the same problem every time I want to resize the Swf file of any flipbook (or Swftools template) as an external load in my main Flash website, through AS3. They always take the whole surface of the screen automatically, even if I’m using the same code for setting external proportions in general… That doesn’t work. I suppose I have to force the internal and encrypted code in those Swf files, because flipbook templates never provide a .fla files or any AS3 (in html it’s ridiculously easy, but unfortunately my entire site is flash-based). Any help? Thanks in advance!

```
var loader:Loader=new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,f);
loader.load(new URLRequest("flipbook.swf"));

function f(e:Event):void{
addChild(loader);
//////RESIZE EXTERNAL LOAD///////
loader.width = 700;
loader.height = 500;
}
////SET LOCATION EXTERNAL LOAD/////
loader.x = 100;
loader.y = 200;
```